# Select all elements after specific element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply some specific styles to all elements which come after a certain element. For example, I want to select all elements which come after the `divider` and change their background color to green.

```
<ul>
  <li> Cricket </li>
  <li> Hockey </li>
  <li class='divider'> </li> //Divider here
  <li> Football </li>
  <li> Table Tennis </li>
</ul>
```

CSS code

```
li {
  background-color: red;
}

//Selector to select elements after divider {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: `li.divider ~ *`? http://jsfiddle.net/9zGen/

Comment: If you can't use a class and have to rely on elements, you can also rely on `nth-child`: [How to use nth-child in CSS to select all elements after a certain one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005703/how-to-use-nth-child-in-css-to-select-all-elements-after-a-certain-one)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can use

```
.divider ~ li {
    background-color:green;
}
```