# How to use nth-child in CSS to select all elements after a certain one?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've seen jQuery has a `:gt(n)` solution, but can the same behavior be achieved in CSS?

What I want is for the mobile website to not have more than 3 elements in some lists. So I would need something along the lines of:

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
   .list li:gt(3) {
      display:none;
   }
}
```

And I want to try avoiding using Javascript for it. Since the `:gt(n)` selector doesn't seem to exist in CSS, can the same selection be achieved with the `:nth-child(n)` selector?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes you can do it using `:nth-child(n+4)`

In your case:

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
   .list li:nth-child(n+4) {
      display:none;
   }
}
```

You can see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wgLCH/2/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .list li:nth-child(n+4) {
      display:none;
   }
}
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wgLCH/1/)**

More info **[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)**

Comment: I believe he needs to hide all elements after the 3rd and not select the third only.

Comment: @AlexIncarnati Sorry, I mis-read it... Thank you... Updated it :)

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child(n+3)` is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
p:nth-child(n+4)
{
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/MA3zR/)