# Create a table collapsible with less/more button?

Tags: javascript, html

I´ve got a table with 50 rows, which is way too much for a website if you look the first time on a page. I want to create a button that can unfold and fold up the whole table.

My big problem is that I have no knowledge about javascript :(.

I don't want to paste here 50 rows of code... Here's a shorter example:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
<! --it should unfold here-->

    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="toggleText()" id="showMore">Show More
</button>
```

Like you see in my example I want to unfold my whole table after 3 rows. What do I have to do to achieve this?

Big thanks and have a nice weekend!

Comment: Hide the `<tr>` elements beyond the third one. [There are nice CSS selectors for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25005703/4543207)

Answer (score 0):

try below javascript code.

```
<script>
      function toggleText() {
        const tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        // initialise i with row number from which you need to hide/show
        for (let i = 3; i < x.length; i++) {
          if (tableRows[i].style.display === "none") {
            tableRows[i].style.display = "table-row";
          } else {
            tableRows[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for this case the Javascript toggle function. Something like that:

```js
const trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");     
const startWith = 3;

function showMore() {       
  for (let i = startWith; i < trs.length; i++) {
    trs[i].classList.toggle('hidden')
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<table id="t">
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>

<! --it should unfold here-->

    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="showMore()" id="showMore">Show More
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment you can simply select the excess table rows with CSS selector logic.

```js
function excerpt(){
  var excessRows = myTable.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(n+4)");
  excessRows.forEach(row => row.style.display = window.getComputedStyle(row).display === "none" ? "block" : "none");
}
```

```css
td { border : 1px solid red}
tr { display : block}
tr:nth-child(n+4) {display : none}
```

```html
<table id = "myTable">
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>row 1 this</td>
        <td>row 1 that</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>row 2 this</td>
        <td>row 2 that</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>row 3 this</td>
        <td>row 3 that</td>
    </tr>

<! --it should unfold here-->

    <tr>
        <td>row 4 this</td>
        <td>row 4 that</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>row 5 this</td>
        <td>row 5 that</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="excerpt()" id="showMore">Show More/Less</button>
```

Comment: Big thank you first of all, is there any possibility to start it folded up, so you can see at the beginning only the first 3 rows?

And is there a code which changes the button from show less to show more at the respective state?

Sorry for asking that much, just try to understand the JS logic.

Have a good week!

Comment: @Vogtei I had to edit my answer to cover your question better. It's important to note that, any CSS attribute initially assigned by the CSS file has to accessed by `window.getComputedStyle(element)[attribute]` rather than `element.style[attribute]` parameter.

Comment: Hey! it worked! thank you:) Do you have any solution to change the show less/more button?