# How to hide the remaining elements after the element position in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using css selector to hide elements but I dont know how to do it in `nth-child`, I want to hide all the remaining elements after the element position 5. How I can do it with nth-child ?

```
<div class="item">item 1</div>
<div class="item">item 2</div>
<div class="item">item 3</div>
<div class="item">item 4</div>
<div class="item">item 5</div> 
<div class="item">item 6</div> // hidden
<div class="item">item 7</div> // hidden
<div class="item">item 8</div> // hidden
...etc...
```

Comment: What have you tried? There's a ton of other questions like yours and many resources online for this.

Comment: @j08691, do you mean like this? `nth-child(n + 5)`

Comment: Yes, but can you post a complete example that didn't work? For example, this works https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yeztpswm/1/ (provided you change 5 to 6)

Comment: Tip: Do some research before posting a question on SO. I googled "css all after nth child" and found [an answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005703/how-to-use-nth-child-in-css-to-select-all-elements-after-the-3rd-one).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
div:nth-child(n+6) {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
div:nth-child(n+6) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">item 1</div>
<div class="item">item 2</div>
<div class="item">item 3</div>
<div class="item">item 4</div>
<div class="item">item 5</div> 
<div class="item">item 6</div> // hidden
<div class="item">item 7</div> // hidden
<div class="item">item 8</div> // hidden
```

[more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: hides 4 and keeps 4 for whatever reason

Comment: In the snippet I'm seeing 1-5 visible, 6-8 hidden, as expected (checked in both Safari and Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to select them using `:nth-child(n+5)`, but only the first 3 divs weren't hidden, not 5. I then tried `.item:nth-child(5) ~ .item`, but now only 4 were visible. I don't know what's up with that, try it for yourself. I think the only workaround is to account for... whatever that error this:

```css
.item:nth-child(n+7) {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="item">item 1</div>
<div class="item">item 2</div>
<div class="item">item 3</div>
<div class="item">item 4</div>
<div class="item">item 5</div> 
<div class="item">item 6</div> <!-- hidden -->
<div class="item">item 7</div> <!-- hidden -->
<div class="item">item 8</div> <!-- hidden -->
<!-- ... -->
```

EDIT: Maybe, it's because that `n` in `:nth-child` ranges not from 0, but from -2. IDK.

Comment: yes this is the same problem for me

Comment: `nth-child` definitely does not start from an index of -2.    FWIW I'm seeing the expected results in this snippet: with `.item:nth-child(n+7) {display: none;}` items 1-6 are visible, checked in current safari and chrome.

Comment: i have items 1-5 visible what is going on here