# css selectors : finding the last sibling of a type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a document that looks like this :

```
<h1>Title A</h1>
<h2>Sub 1</h2>
<h1 class='foo'>Title B</h1>
<h2>Sub 2</h2>
<h2>Sub 3</h2>
<h1>C</h1>
<h2>Sub 4</h2>
```

And I'd like to select Sub 2 and 3, because they are after Title B, a h1 with class foo. However, Sub 4 doen't interest me be cause the previous h1 is of class foo.

I know I could put div around each block beginning with h1, but my content is generated via markdown, so the only way is to change the DOM once the page is loaded, and it feels dirty and cumbersome.

My question is kinda related to this one [How to select all elements after specific element in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106089/how-to-select-all-elements-after-specific-element-in-css) but I lack the "back to normal" behavior once a regular h1 is seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` to select the `<h2>` tags after the `<h1>` with the class `.foo` and use it again to "reset" the CSS properties after the next `<h1>` tag :

```css
.foo ~ h2 {
  color: red;
}
.foo ~ h1 ~ h2 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title A</h1>
<h2>Sub 1</h2>
<h1 class='foo'>Title B</h1>
<h2>Sub 2</h2>
<h2>Sub 3</h2>
<h2>Sub 4</h2>
<h2>Sub 5</h2>
<h1>C</h1>
<h2>Sub 6</h2>
<h2>Sub 7</h2>
```

This example will change the color of all the h2 tags after the `.foo` element (*this means you can have as many as you want*)  and reset it to black after the next `h1` tag.

Comment: I prefer hiero's answer unless you need to support any number of `<h2>`s here, or need IE7 support (both work in IE8).

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of using it to describe "one that follow one that follow foo", it's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: As I don't know the number of h2's, this is cleaner. (I realize I didn't specify it in my question, sorry)

Comment: Bolt, the + selector isn't updated correctly in IE7 if you insert elements in certain places (according to quirksmode at least).  I consider buggy, conditional support to be not supported.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/70zxd3h8/

```
.foo + h2, .foo + h2 + h2 {
    background:red;
}
```

Or h2:nth-of-type(2), h2:nth-of-type(3)